# How do I add letter grades into a existing list

Tags: python, list, append

I'm required to add letter grades into an existing list that has the student ID and student points ranging from 0-100.
I think that I need to append the letter grades into the list but I don't even know how to convert the numbers into the letter grades yet.

```
student_grades = []
for i in range(0,20):
    student_grades.append(s[i])

for student in student_grades:
    Data = student.split("\t")
    letter_grade = Data[1]

if (80 <= Data <= 100):
    letter_grade = 'A'
elif (65 <= Data <= 79):
    letter_grade = 'B'
elif (50 <= Data <= 64):
    letter_grade = 'C'
elif (35 <= Data <= 49):
    letter_grade = 'D'
else:
    letter_grade = 'F'
print(letter_grade)
```

But every time I try to run it, with different variations to the if statements, the programme responses with `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`

Edit: is there a more efficient way to do this? My workbook tells me that I need to "define a function which calculates the letter grade for a student based on their mark. That is, the mark that is passed in a parameter, and it returns the appropriate letter (as a string). The conversion is based on the following table:
A     80 - 100
B     65 - 79
C     50 - 64
D     35 - 49
E      0 - 34

Comment: This `Data = student.split("\t")` sets `Data` to a string value (i.e. some text) or a group of string values, while `80` and `100` are a integer values, so when you state `(80 <= Data <= 100)`, you are comparing a string value to an integer value and Python is telling you that doesn't work. You need to turn the text into a number first, if you're sure it represents a number, using something like `int()`

Comment: To parse `Data` from string to integer, just do `int(Data)`. Try replacing all the conditions where it is `Data` with that.

Comment: that was able to do it for one of my grades. How can I loop through all my grades like this? Do I need to put a range around it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Grismar and @revliscano have pointed out important notice about data types int and str. Here's a working code example:

```py
student_grades = []
# This is a list of grade numbers. for example, `[20,17,61]`. I assume that you 
# store student names and ID and other information on another list.


# The following line of code will throw an exception if `student_grades` has 
# incorrect format
for x in student_grades:
    assert isinstance(x,(int,float))

# while `isinstance` is `python`'s built-in function to judge if `x` is of 
# type `int` or `float`, both are acceptable for grades.

def letter_grade(num):
    letter = None
    if num < 35:
        letter = 'F'
    elif num < 50:
        letter = 'D'
    elif num < 65:
        letter = 'C'
    elif num < 80:
        letter = 'B'
    else:
        letter = 'A'
    return letter
# Note how rewriting the cases make the conditions concise.


converted_grades = [letter_grade(num) for num in student_grades]
print(converted_grades)
```

Now I wrap it in a function to make it easier to use.

```py
def num_to_letter(nums):
    def letter_grade(num):
        letter = None
        if isinstance(num,(int,float)):
            if num < 35:
                letter = 'F'
            elif num < 50:
                letter = 'D'
            elif num < 65:
                letter = 'C'
            elif num < 80:
                letter = 'B'
            else:
                letter = 'A'
        return letter
    return [letter_grade(num) for num in nums]
```

Some tests:

```py
print(num_to_letter([1,50,80]))
>> ['F', 'C', 'A']

print(num_to_letter([1,50,'invalid_score']))
>> ['F', 'C', None]
```

If the data type is incorrect, the function leaves the letter grade as `None` without throwing an exception.